# Subprocess.run - Kill process in Python

Tags: python, subprocess

In python I need to use Subprocess like that:

```
subprocess.run(cmd, text=True,shell=True,cwd=self.cwd,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Unfortunatelly the process sometimes gets stuck. So I need to check the timeout manually ( via threading... ) I know there is some option with `.Popen`, but there the timeout is not reliable and the process gets stuck also.

My question: If the `Subprocess.run(...)` gets stuck, how to terminate (kill) it? There is  bunch of hint when using `.Popen`, but I could not find any with `.run`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your Python code is blocking waiting for `run` to finish, so unless you resort to threading, how is it supposed to do _anything at all_ here? Use `Popen` instead when you need things `run` can't do.

Comment: `subprocess.run` blocks until the command is complete.  You will have to convert to `Popen`.  `run` is implemented by using `Popen`, so you can look at the source code to get hints.

Comment: Mind, `shell=True` is generally a bad idea and adds a lot of complexity to what's going on under the hood at runtime. I'd want to get into the details of your specific process and how it works, but for a lot of simpler cases using `subprocess.run(['timeout', '30', 'commandname', 'arg1', ..])` can be appropriate, if you're on an OS that provides a `timeout` command (modern GNU-flavored Linuxy systems fall into that category).

Comment: When you say that "timeout is not reliable and the process gets stuck there also" -- one of the reasons that can happen is the timeout delivering a SIGTERM _to the shell that `shell=True` starts_, instead of delivering it to the program the shell ran. You can avoid that by writing your shell command so the shell `exec`s the final executable, or you can just _not use a shell at all_. When it's feasible, the latter is generally the best option.

Comment: From manual: _The recommended approach to invoking subprocesses is to use the run() function for all use cases it can handle. For more advanced use cases, the underlying Popen interface can be used directly._
Anyway when I use `Shell=False` and use `timeout=myTimeout` - it seems to work. But: after cx_Freeze the app. The "like shell window" is opened when the subprocess is launched. When `shell = True` this does not happen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**
Instead of using `subprocess.run(...)` I used `subprocess.check_output` (I wanted to have it like a blocking function until the subprocess finishs or the timeout occures).

I already found out that for my (and many others application) is better to set `shell=False`!

**Now with all these configuration, the timeout in subprocess works reliably!**

Also I added param. `creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW` which causes to not opening an empty shell window when calling *subprocess* in my *.exe* version of my app (using cx_Freeze).